# How do I align a TextFormField and Text widget inside a row in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter, I would like to align the text widget shown in the screen shot to the bottom of the row so it is on the same line as the text form field. I would like to move "Kilos" to the bottom of the row.

[image: Screen shot of emulator]

Here is the code:

```
  return Row(
    children: [
      Flexible(
        child: TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: label),
          keyboardType: _getKeyboardType(),
          validator: (value) => _getFormValidator()(value),
          onSaved: (value) { saveAction(formItem,value); },
          onTap: () {print(TextInputType.emailAddress);},
        ),
      ),
      Text('Kilos',style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.red),)
    ],
  );
```

I have tried wrapping the Row and the Text widgets within an Align widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with intrinsic height and make your `crossAlignment.end`

```
IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "label"),
                     /* keyboardType: _getKeyboardType(),
                      validator: (value) => _getFormValidator()(value),
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        saveAction(formItem, value);
                      },*/
                      onTap: () {
                        print(TextInputType.emailAddress);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Kilos',
                  style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked simply with the "CrossAxisAlignment.end" attribute. Sorry, I'm new to dart and didn't understand that end meant the bottom with CrissAxisAlignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with Stack..
here is sample code.

```
Stack(
    children: [
      TextFormField(
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Enter a search term'
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          child: Text(
            'Kilos',
            style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
          ))
    ],
  ),
```

[image]